# Cassandra - conflict resolution for mixed column updates with identical timestamp

Tags: cassandra

I would like to know which write wins in case of two updates with the same client timestamp.

Initial data: `KeyA: { col1:"val AA", col2:"val BB", col3:"val CC"}`

Client 1 sends update: `KeyA: { col1:"val C1", col2:"val B1"}`

Client 2 sends update: `KeyA: { col1:"val C2", col2:"val B2"}`

**Both updates have the same timestamp**.

What result will be returned by row query on `KeyA` ?

1. `{ col1:"val C1", col2:"val B1", col3:"val CC"}` - Clint 1 wins
2. `{ col1:"val C2", col2:"val B2", col3:"val CC"}` - Client 2 wins
3. `{ col1:"val C2", col2:"val B1", col3:"val CC"}` - mixed update

I expect, that result is unpredictable - since both updates have the same timestamp.

Is mixed scenario also possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timestamps are a property of each column not the entire insert itself. Multiple columns with the same exact timestamp are resolved by comparing the actual column value itself. This is done by comparing the values lexically by bytes, so that the value returned is deterministic.

So in your example, if every column inserted by both clients had the same exact timestamp, you could see a mixed update depending on how the actual column values compare.

Comment: In my example above mixed update is not possible, but only because column values from Client 2 have higher byte value - right?

Comment: Cassandra offers atomic writes and isolation level - but this guaranties only that 1) mutation on single row will be applied as whole, or rejected 2) mutation will be visible after all columns are written. BUT the fact that single mutation have stored 10 columns for single row, does not mean that all those 10 columns will be returned by read query, because second parallel mutation with the same timestamp could store other values for the same columns. Right?

Comment: Yes, in your example the values from client 2 would be returned. Also, the row level isolation does not guarantee the values from a write will be returned if the timestamps for the columns in the write are not the most recent ones available.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a post I wrote a while ago about [Cassandra Timestamps](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2010/11/timestamps-in-cassandra.html) and conflicts.

Comment: How does column with collection type handle conflicts ?