# conflict resolution for mixed row updates with identical timestamp

Tags: cassandra

This is not duplicate on my previous post - now I would like to concentrate now on mixed row update.

Two clients send updates on two rows identified by the same key (`RowA` and `RowB`). Rows are persisted in the same Column Family. Both requests have **the same timestamp**.

- Client 1 sends insert: `RowA:{col:"valA1"}, RowB:{col:"valB1"}`
- Client 2 sends insert: `RowA:{col:"valA2"}, RowB:{col:"valB2"}`

What is the result of such update ?

Is is possible that one on the clients winns, because we have update within the same column family?

Is mixed result possible - for example `RowA:{col :"valA1"}, RowB:{col:"valB2"}` ?

Is is possible to predict result of such update?

Comment: Doesn't sound similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602413/cassandra-conflict-resolution-for-mixed-column-updates-with-identical-timestam ? Are they two problems?

Comment: Timestamps are specific to each column in cassandra. So this is the same question as your previous one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602413/cassandra-conflict-resolution-for-mixed-column-updates-with-identical-timestam/) which I have answered there.

Comment: could be not the same, because Cassandra could do "something more" with its atomic writes - this is the reason why I wanted to split it over two questions: one with single row modification and second with mutate on two rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two Writes to the same row/column have the same time stamp, then the tie is broken by comparing the byte values of the columns, see [CASSANDRA-1039](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1039) for details.

In the example you give above, client2's writes would win, as client 2 is writing values with byte[]'s that are greater than client 1's.

As others have pointed out, this write,

```
RowA:{col:"valA1"}, RowB:{col:"valB1"}
```

Is the same as two writes,

```
 RowA:{col:"valA1"}
 RowB:{col:"valB1"}
```